# Can i move the attachment location to the top of the list form in 2007 SharePoint?

Tags: 2007, list, attachments

I already have the attachment first in my list order but it always appears on the bottom of the form that opens up when you edit the item which makes it hard to navigate to for users. Is their a way to move it to the top or link to the attachment with the paperclip icon on the list?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes create a new display form and move this field

```
<td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="80%">
                        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="AttachmentsField" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Attachments" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u','AttachmentsField','Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Attachments')}"/>
                        <script>
      var elm = document.getElementById(&quot;idAttachmentsTable&quot;);
      if (elm == null || elm.rows.length == 0)
      document.getElementById(&quot;idAttachmentsRow&quot;).style.display=&apos;none&apos;;
    </script>
                    </td>
```

In the top row of the html table